# How to make an object "live" in Javascript without tying it to the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

I asked in IRC chat yesterday whether it was possible to have an element update with any changes to an object it references, rather than just keep the value it was given upon being declared. For example

```
Arr1 = [1,2,3]
i1 = Arr1.length-1
last1 = Arr1[i1]

Arr1.push(4)
```

Checking `last1` at the end of this (arbitrary) example shows it has not updated to reflect the newly added value of 4, so objects in JS aren't "live" by default.

I'm a beginner but I'd worked this out from practice already, but was told this was actually the case... I guess my question wasn't understood.

`NodeList` objects are "live" however, and I'm wondering if there are other types of object in JS that do so, as it would obviously save lines of code spent updating them.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what live means, because even if `Arr1` were a NodeList, last1 would still remain unchanged.  Live in the context of node lists means that if you update the DOM, the node list updates as well.

Comment: No I know, I wasn't being totally strict on the meaning of "live" and I do understand the DOM, I'm just interested to hear if this kind of problem is often encountered and if there are alternative ways to do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important distinction here is that `i1` does not "reference" anything here. It is simply storing the numeric result of the expression `Arr1.length-1` when that line executed. Likewise, `last1` may or may not reference the value that was the third element of `Arr1` when line 3 executed, but it maintains no reference to `Arr1` itself or anything about it.

As in some other programming languages, variables that are assigned to objects *are* references, so you can do this:

```
var obj1 = { prop1: "hello", prop2: "goodbye" };
var obj2 = obj1;
obj2.prop1 = "buongiorno";
console.log(obj1.prop1);  // result is "buongiorno"
```

But this doesn't seem to be quite what you're describing.

It sounds like what you're describing is some sort of reactive programming. JavaScript doesn't really work the way you're imagining, but you could accomplish this using closures:

```
var Arr1 = [1,2,3];
var i1 = function() { return Arr1.length - 1; };
var last1 = function() { return Arr1[i1()]; };

console.log(i1());    // result is 2
console.log(last1()); // result is 3

Arr1.push(4);

console.log(i1());    // result is 3
console.log(last1()); // result is 4
```

Note that here, the `()` parentheses at the end are required to call these functions and get their current value.

One even trickier thing you could do is the following:

```
function capture(fcn) { 
    return { valueOf: fcn, toString: function() { return fcn().toString(); } };
}

var Arr1 = [1,2,3]
var i1 = capture(function() { return Arr1.length - 1; });
var last1 = capture(function() { return Arr1[i1]; });

console.log(last1 * 5); // result is 15

Arr1.push(4);

console.log(last1 * 5); // result is 20
```

Note however that this second technique has its limitations. You have to coerce the values into the type that you would expect or call their `.valueOf()` method in order for them to produce an actual value. If you just used:

```
console.log(last1);
```

You would not get any sort of friendly result.

Comment: Ah thanks for updating your answer - that's actually a lot more like what I had in mind! Using functions seems a bit awkward, especially since it's bad practice to declare them inside loops. The fact that they themselves are just objects (made with the function constructor) suggested to me there should be a way. Cheers for the huge answer!

Comment: One question though - is there a way to refer to these properties...? Like `obj1.properties.length` or something? `obj1.length` is `undefined` and I still want to manipulate it like an array

Comment: …to answer my own question, `Object.keys(obj1).length`

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question as why are some variables which are copies are updated when you change the original value and others are not.

This is because some types of variables are Reference Types and others are Value Types. Numbers, dates and strings are value types and are copied whenever you assign them to a variable. Objects, Arrays (which are also an Object) are reference types and are not copied, just referenced.

This example is using value types and any change to the first variable will not be copied:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = foo; // this is copying the value from the foo variable to bar
foo = 2;
console.log(bar); // 1
```

compared to the same thing but with a reference to an object:

```
var foo = {prop:1};
var bar = foo; // this is creating a reference to the foo object
foo.prop = 2;
console.log(bar.prop); // 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the info this is exactly what I had in mind